# Code example for AWS Java Lambda to connect with RDS Postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

I wanted the code example for the following AWS Serverless program.

I wanted to write Java Lambda to connect with Postgres SQL and store the data and retrieve the data. I am not able to find the documentation properly.

Also, need a dependency for pom.xml.
I have cluster identifier, DB name, and DB credentials.

How to connect with Postgres DB in a serverless way?
How to query it?
Code example for Java

Answer (score 0):

> How to connect with Postgres DB in a serverless way?

There isn't a "serverless' way to connect to a standard PostgreSQL database. You have to use standard JDBC connections just like any other Java app. You might look into using [Amazon RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/) to eliminate some of the issues inherent in connecting serverless functions to a standard RDS database.

If you switched to an [Amazon Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) database, then you could utilize the [Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html), which is a great solution for serverless database queries.

Comment: I have Amazon Aurora Serverless Postgres database only. Now, I want to write Java code to connect with database and create table, query it and store it. Any code sample please?

Comment: Then use the Data API.